# My new page theme does not appear properly

Tags: wordpress, web

i just set up a new website. I uploaded word-press using c panel. But when i go my website Here's an link to http://poissoncomposite.com., index of/ cg-bin and WP appear and web site does not. I just want to see my theme directly when i go to my website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better fits on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com Please do **not** double post. Either wait for migration or delete the question here and reask there.

Answer (score 0):

Through your filemanager of ftp just move all the files from wp into the root folder ( i.e '/' ) Or if your host doesn't allow that, then point your domain to /wp instead of /